# Using getChildByName to find a button using a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Quick question.. I think :)

I am trying to chance the hue of a button inside af movieclip. The movieclip is called 'container' and the button is named 'traps' (which I get from another variable elsewhere).

This is my code

```
function get_muscle(muscle:String, tension:String):void {
    if (tension == 'primary') {
        var getChild:MovieClip = MovieClip(container.getChildByName(muscle));

        greenHue(getChild);
    }

}
```

Sadly it does not work. If i type in greenHue(container.traps) manually it works fine, but when I try to do it like this, it does not work. I have also tried to just use greenHue(container.muscle) but that does not work either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getChildByName searches the children of the container for a element has a name property that is equal to what you pass in.

So does container.traps.name == muscle?

Also what is the type of container.traps? You said it is a button but you try to cast it to MovieClip.

Comment: I have the following
A movieclip called 'container' which holds several buttons inside it. One of these is called 'traps'.
I have a var called muscle which is == 'traps'.

Comment: Yeah than what you are trying won't work because variable name is not the same thing as the name property. getChildByName checks the property called name not the actual variable name. You can try "container['traps'] as Button" or "container[muscle] as Button" to get the button dynamically.

Comment: I think I got your point. Anyways I got it working by doing like this var getChild = container.getChildByName(muscle); Thanks!

Comment: Or as you just said.. greenHue(container[muscle]); MUCH simpler :D